# Where does pip install the anyserver.py file when installing web2py?

Tags: python, pip, web2py

I ran

```
bash: pip install web2py
```

inside of a virtualenv. I can see that web2py is installed:

```
bash: ls bin/w2p*
bin/w2p_apps    bin/w2p_clone   bin/w2p_run
```

and that the relevant libraries are in my site-packages directory:

```
bash: ls -al lib/python2.7/site-packages/gluon/
<a long list of web2py libraries>
```

however, I can't seem to:

```
bash: find . -name anyserver.py
```

or:

```
bash: sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb; locate anyserver.py
```

(both commands return no results).

In this context, where does pip install the anyserver.py file (or, more accurately, does it install anyserver at all)?

Comment: try: updatedb; locate anyserver.py

Comment: or sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb; locate anyserver.py on a mac ;)

Comment: You're probably better off not pip installing web2py, as the PyPI version is far out of date and currently not being maintained (this may change).

Comment: @Anthony do you have a link to a currently maintained version?

Comment: Just download the [source code](http://www.web2py.com/examples/static/web2py_src.zip) and unzip.